# How To Fix Center A Pop-Up Div At Scolled Position

Tags: javascript, html, css

I know that

```
position: fixed;
```

is used to stop the scrolling of the page but this is sending me back to the top of the page and centering the div there. How can i have the pop-up div appear at the center of the position that the user has scrolled to while disabling page scroll?

here is some more relevant code

```css
.body_div.act{
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.overlay{
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 20;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0 , 0, 0, 0.75);
}

.pop_up_save{
  display: none;
  z-index: 25;
  padding: 25px;
  width: 600px;
  height: 800px;
  margin: auto;
  position: fixed;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
  border-radius: 50px;
  background-color: #1A1A19;
  border: 1px solid white;
}
.pop_up_save.active{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="body_div" id="body_div_id">
    <div id="overlay_id"></div>
    <div class="pop_up_save"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Possible Solution

Add `overflow` to `hidden` on `body` element, when popup is active/open and use `position: fixed` declaration on popup container

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <style>
      body {
          margin: 0;
      }
      .pop_up_open {
          overflow: hidden;
      }
      .pop_up_open .pop_up_overlay{
          position: fixed;
          width: 100vw;
          height: 100vh;
          background-color: rgba(0 , 0, 0, 0.75);
          z-index: 20;
      }
      .pop_up_save{
          display: none;
          position: fixed;
          top:0;
          left:0;
          width: 100%;
          height: 100%;
          z-index: 25;
      }
      .pop_up_open .pop_up_save {
          padding-right: 17px;
          overflow-x: hidden;
          overflow-y: auto;
          display: block;
      }
      .pop_up_save_inner {
          width: 100%;
          max-width: 600px;
          height: 800px;
          padding: 25px;
          margin: auto;
          border-radius: 50px;
          background-color: #1A1A19;
          border: 1px solid white;
      }
    </style>
</head>
<body class="pop_up_open">
    <div class="pop_up_overlay"></div>
    <div class="pop_up_save active">
        <div class="pop_up_save_inner">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```